# Find Largest Positive Even Number in C with help of Loops and Printing Relevant message if there is no Such Number Present

Tags: c, loops

Write a program to input 10 numbers and find the largest positive even number .**In case no such number is present
a relevant message should be printed**.
I'm stuck while writing the code for printing **the relevant message** (if there is no such number present). What to do ?

Here's how I tried...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a,lar;
    printf("Enter the first number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    lar = a;
    for (int i = 2; i <=10; i++)
    {
        printf("Number %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if (a > 0 && (a % 2) == 0)
        {
            if (a > lar)
            {
                lar = a;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The largest positive even number is : %d",lar);
}
```

Also the code is returning wrong value if I enter all odd numbers.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Then also please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You skip all the tests (positive, even) for the first number. Why?

Comment: Why aren't you getting the first number in the loop as well?

Comment: Please elaborate what kind of problem you have and show your best attempt. Do you think your code as shown has only the problem of not giving an appropriate message? Your question is unclear, because as asked the answer would be "use an appropriate printf, even without any special parameters, in an appropriate `else`." Which of course refers to the fact that you only ask about making a suitable output, but not about all the other parts of the task,  like actually detecting that the message is needed....

Comment: Consider improving your question to the point that all info needed for answering is there and then creating your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "lar" as a flag showing whether there was a positive even number in the input or not. To do that, you set it first to a negative number (e.g. -1). If there is even a single positive even number in the input, that number will overwrite lar and it won't be negative at the end of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a,lar;
    lar = -1; 
    for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
    {
        printf("Number %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if (a > 0 && (a % 2) == 0)
        {
            if (a > lar)
            {
                lar = a;
            }
        }
    }

    if(lar > 0)
    {
        printf("The largest positive even number is : %d",lar);
    }
    else
    {
        print("There are no positive even numbers.")
    }
}
```